Does air create a high pressure zone once the low pressure zone is filled in?
So say you have a sphere of low pressure air (let's say a 0.5 atm sphere in a 1 atm environment). Air would rush to fill in the low pressure, therefore it would accelerate to the center of it. Wouldn't that acceleration make it so when the air stopped (because the low pressure was filled in), it would become high pressure?
The same way a stream of air being accelerated into a wall will make high pressure where it meets the wall.
If that didn't make sense, here's another way of explaining it: The air accelerates into the center of the low pressure sphere, and then when it fills the sphere in with normal pressure air, there is still the velocity vector from all of the air accelerating into the center of the sphere. Wouldn't that velocity then dissipate its energy and slow down by making the center of the sphere higher pressure?

One of the reasons I'm asking this is if this is true and it does make a high pressure zone, it seems like it'd make some sort of oscillation. So the now higher pressure sphere would extend out, and make a low pressure doing so (accelerating air = lower pressure). Then that low pressure air would pull in higher pressure air, repeating the process again and again.

You might want to look into cavity resonance.

The best you can do by decelerating the air is recover the original pressure.

You are touching on the fact that air has mass, therefore moving air has momentum.  In this question the writer wonders about pressure changes when a front passes.
If colder air is denser near the ground, how can a warm front ever advance?

momentum of moving air (wind) will increase pressure in the direction of its movement

So, wind converging on a low pressure area will create a pressure peak as it fills in the volume.  This is seen in water as a "rogue" wave phenomenon.  We may also see it in an "upwash" following a strong downwash created by a large heavy wing.
What this means is that air is compressible at lower speeds, but in an open system the converging pressure peak will be short-lived.
Locally, air viscosity will dampen the "spring" and air movement will stop once pressures equalize.

Ah okay, so basically because the air is pretty incompressible at lower speeds, the pressure peak is smaller/short lived?

Yes, that is correct.

Depending on the magnitude of the pressure difference, you might not need compressibility to explain what happens at all.  At low pressure ratio, this is just an acoustic pulse.
First, don't think about the sphere as a sphere.  Start by thinking about one radial line -- starting at the center of the sphere, extending out to infinitely far away.  Start by thinking just along this line.
Now we have a 1D line arranged from left to right, with an initial low pressure at the one side and a higher pressure at the other side, with some membrane between them -- then you instantaneously destroy the membrane.  What happens?
This is a classical shock tube problem.  Think of a steel pipe in the basement  of a building on a university campus.  One end is sealed, the opposite end is open to the atmosphere.   The membrane (somewhere in the middle) might be a thin sheet of plastic.  The sealed side is pressurized, then the membrane is punctured.  The tube has a bunch of really high speed pressure and temperature sensors.  You measure what happens in the brief moment after the membrane is popped.
You can vary the pressure ratio -- usually we use a pressure ratio high enough to create a shockwave (compressible flow), but without such high ratios is just an acoustic pressure pulse.
Some shock tubes use different gasses on each side -- say carbon dioxide or helium on one side and air on the other.  In order to get to higher pressure ratios, some shock tubes seal both ends and pressurize one side while drawing the other side down to a vacuum.  Although the membrane can be a thin sheet of plastic, I've seen one where it was a thick metal plate -- similar to a manhole cover.
This problem can be modeled by something called the wave equation.  For the shock tube, we can use the 1D wave equation.  For the spherical problem, we use the 3D wave equation.
Because of spherical symmetry, we can actually perform a transformation to turn your 3D problem in cartesian coordinates into a 1D problem in spherical coordinates.  Instead of a constant area tube like a pipe, you now have a tube whose cross sectional area increases in one direction -- like a cone.  Because this is a change of variables, we can book-keep that $1/r^2$ term in different places if we need to.
When the membrane is released, not only does a high pressure pulse move inward, a low pressure pulse spreads outward.
Another way of thinking about the spherical problem is as a whole bunch of point sources spread on the surface of a sphere.  Any two point sources will  interact, creating places where their peaks add together and other places where they cancel out.  In the spherical problem, all the point sources on the surface of the sphere are interfering -- this creates an amplified wave that gets stronger as you come to the center of the sphere.
When the waves reach the center, you can have two perspectives.  One is they've reached the end of the tube -- the apex of the cone.  Hitting a rigid boundary, they reflect back the way they've come.
The wave moving inward actually induces a velocity in that direction -- that can't continue with the wall, so the reflected wave creates a condition with zero velocity at the wall.
However, if you think of the sphere as a whole bunch of point sources interfering with each other -- when the propagating waves reach the center, they pass through one another, but now instead of getting stronger, as they continue to propagate past the center of the sphere, they cancel each other out and get weaker as they spread.
I know this is a long answer, but I wanted to give you different ideas for the direction this kind of question can take.
Are you most interested in the compressible flow aspect -- you might want to spend time researching shock tubes.
Are you most interested in the low pressure acoustic propagation -- you should look into how sound propagates.
Are you most interested in the 3D effects of it being a spherical problem?  Or was that just a way for you to think of a physical situation that made sense to ask the question?
I disagree that this post should have been moved from Aviation to Physics -- while I realize it isn't about airplanes, Aviation SE is the de-facto Aerospace Engineering SE, and this question is very squarely appropriate there.  Someone who cares should advocate for creating an Aerospace Engineering SE separate from Aviation...

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Note that the condition you describe upon implosion of a spherical space, and the rebound that would occur, actually does take place in the real world when a submarine exceeds its crush depth. The air inside is violently compressed and collapses upon itself, creating high pressure at the center of the collapse- and then the air bounces back (it rebounds) and expands outwards. It then collapses a second time.
This creates a unique acoustic signature called a bubble pulse which can be detected with hydrophones a significant distance away from the crushed sub. The navy takes the detection of a bubble pulse as proof that a submarine has been sunk.
